# How to get OpenStreetMaps or OpenTilesMaps API for personal android project?

Tags: android, gis, openstreetmap, openmaptiles

So, I think StackOverflow is the best place for asking this question.
I have a personal project in my Academy, I want to make an android app that can use for tracking our track when we are on the mountain.
This app will run offline and use GPS because the mountain signal is mostly weak. So, how to get the API OSM or OpenTilesMaps? I hope u can give me the reference for that. It's very helping me

I've searched some option for Mapping there are Google Maps, OpenStreetMap, and OpenTilesMaps.
I don't want to use Google Maps API because it's not free now.
So i choose OpenStreetMap or OpenTilesMaps

Comment: There are already various questions about downloading tiles for offline use. Also consider using vector tiles as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks before, sorry if i make a mistakes of my question
but it's so helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For offline apps, try following web app to create OSM tile packages
https://apl.esri.com/jg/OSMVectorTileExport/index.html
or install QGIS and follow below link. https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html

Comment: Oke i will try it. If it work i will back to give my result. Thank's